# SPARQL query for returning individual data

Tags: sparql, ontology

I have the following query to return all the properties with their respective values using SPARQL:

```
select distinct ?property ?value
where {
     ?instance a df:Tools . 
     ?instance ?property ?value  }
```

The example of the output is:

```
Name    "EnCase"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>
```

Is there a way to make the value field only output: "EnCase", instead of the entire property value? I am new to SPARQL and ontologies, but this would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`STR`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) to convert convert the value to a plain literal:

```
select distinct ?property ?plain_value
where {
     ?instance a df:Tools . 
     ?instance ?property ?value
     BIND(STR(?value) AS ?plain_value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you :P, works perfectly